# Supabase Trigger on email verification

Tags: supabase

I saw this question has been asked a couple of times before, but the code suggested doesn't work for me. Even the docs don't seem to have functional code.

It seems like I need to create a function first and then a trigger? I'm not sure why, but it says `Failed to create database function: failed to create pg.functions: syntax error at or near "create"`

```
-- inserts a row into public.profiles
create function public.handle_new_user()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
security definer set search_path = public
as $$
begin
  insert into public.profiles (id, first_name, age)
  values (new.id, new.raw_user_meta_data ->> 'first_name', new.raw_user_meta_data['age']::integer);
  return new;
end;
$$;

-- trigger the function every time a user is created
create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_new_user();
```

I read the suggestion on this and modified the script, but that has the same error.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Supabase/comments/z1atwu/trigger_on_email_verification/

Answer (score 0):

I realized you can just execute the suggestions in the sql mode, for some reason the same syntax doesn't work when creating a specific function

Answer (score 0):

For creating functions and triggers I found the SQL Editor to be the best option, some things can't be done using the ui.

You first need to define your postgresql function. The one you showed is correct.
Here is mine, I just add more fields to my new table:

```
create function public.handle_verified_user()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
security definer set search_path = public
as $$
begin
    insert into public.users (id, created_at, full_name, email)
    values (new.id, new.created_at, new.raw_user_meta_data ->> 'full_name', new.email);
    return new;
end;
$$;
```

Then you define the trigger for executing the function when the "last_sign_in_at" value changes from NULL to not being NULL anymore, that way the trigger only runs once, when the user actually verifies the email and logs in.

```
create trigger on_auth_user_verify_email
after
update on auth.users for each row when (
  old.last_sign_in_at is null
  and new.last_sign_in_at is not null
)
execute procedure public.handle_verified_user ();
```

You can verify the function and the trigger have been created on the supabase dashboard.

Good luck and I hope this helps you!